# Is it possible to return a table of all affected rows from multiple Postgres UPDATEs inside a LOOP?

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

## Overview

This question regards Postgres.

Consider a scenario where we loop over some auxiliary data returned from an initial SELECT, and use the data to UPDATE another table `x` at each iteration.

**Question: once the loop is complete, is it possible to return all affected rows from all iterations?**

---

## Details

- Goal is to use raw SQL, not a function. But if it's possible using a function, do give pointers as to how this can be achieved.
- This happens inside a transaction
- I have tried combinations of `RETURNING *` and `RETURN` placed just after the `END LOOP` (see below), but that throws syntax errors.
- In short, I want to return all rows from `ordercountsbyorderdate` that were modified by the `UPDATE` inside the loop.

```
DO $$
  DECLARE
      new_order RECORD;
      existing_order_row RECORD;
      existing_order_count NUMERIC;
  BEGIN
      FOR new_order IN (SELECT * FROM new_orders_by_date)
      LOOP
          -- Try and find a matching row in table 'ordercountsbyorderdate' for the new order date
          SELECT * FROM ordercountsbyorderdate
          WHERE orderdate = new_order.orderdate AND item = new_order.item
          ORDER BY orderdate desc
          LIMIT 1
          INTO existing_order_row;

          -- If found, store the existing order count, otherwise default to 0
          IF FOUND THEN
              existing_order_count = existing_order_row.ordercount;
          ELSE
              existing_order_count = 0;
          END IF;

          -- If necessary, insert a new order counts row, for this new order
          INSERT INTO ordercountsbyorderdate (item, orderdate, ordercount)
          SELECT new_order.item, new_order.orderdate, existing_order_count
          WHERE NOT EXISTS 
          (
              SELECT * FROM ordercountsbyorderdate 
              WHERE orderdate = new_order.orderdate AND item = new_order.item
          );

          -- Update the ordercounts for all applicable dates.
          -- If the order count is increased for a year ago, it must cascade forward
          -- If this is a newly inserted row, we insert the new order count fresh.
          -- If this is an update to a row, we add new order count to the existing.
          UPDATE ordercountsbyorderdate
              SET ordercount = ordercount + new_order.ordercount
              WHERE orderdate >= new_order.orderdate AND item = new_order.item
      END LOOP;
  END$$;
```

Comment: In a function Yes, in a DO-statement No. From the manual: `The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void.`

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks. I've just updated my post to remove the strict restriction of 'no functions'. Any pointers on how it can be achieved with a function is welcome

Comment: To be honest, I think all logic in this code can be replaced by a single INSERT statement using an ON CONFLICT resolution to do the UPDATEs. Could you share the DDL for the tables involved, including the constraints? (and if possible some data) See https://dbfiddle.uk/S9ZOHCkV

Comment: I would say that `ordercountsbyorderdate` is completely unnecessary. A simple select on the target table would give you the results you need? `select item, orderdate, count(*) from yourtable group by item, orderdate` no need to waste operations to get it.

Comment: Sorry, I had simplified the example to reduce the question down to its core so no DDL yet. I've now added a bit more of the detail in, to highlight complexities. Working on getting a dbfiddle example ready

Comment: This conversation is an example of why SO requests you include a [mre] rather than just a description. It avoids ambiguity, gives clear success criteria, and gives us something to experiment with. Please edit your question with a complete [mre].

Comment: @JorgeCampos In theory yes, but the reason for this logic is to ensure that the the `ordercountsbyorderdate` is up to date, as far back in time as is required. The `new_orders_by_date` needs to trigger a cascade of updates to all order counts for all impacted dates (and the order counts roll over day by day, so an update to an order count a year ago will need to roll forward onto all counts since then).

Comment: Create a temporary table before the loop, insert into it what you want to return, then return select * from the temp table after the loop. Or better yet, don't use a stored proc; use app code.

Comment: It is not theory it is fact. If your main table have the dates the query I show you will have the most up to date data whenever you run it for whatever time in present or past (it is grouping by date). This whole thing you built with two different tables to have counts is waste of resources and computation process. Anyways, the best suggestion for this is the one's @Bohemian gave up here..

Comment: You can pipe a result set and add rows as needed. Or, you can create a temp table, insert all rows there and then return the temp table.